# Memory leak when using runOnUiThread

Tags: android

I am a newbie in Android, so please be patient.

I am getting a memory leak while executing runOnUiThread according to Android Studio Profiler. This thread is used to perform a network operation and call a method within the UI (record a log). It should be a very simple operation.

I have tried not staring a new thread each minute instead of using Looper. But, I get similar results to using runOnUiThread and I still get a memory leak.

Here's my code below:

```
class SendPost extends Thread {

    public void run() {
       if (Looper.myLooper() == null)
            {
              Looper.prepare();
            }
       Handler handler = new Handler();
       ...

       MainActivity.instance.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainActivity.instance.actualizeLog();
            }
        });

      handler.postDelayed(this,60000);
      Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

How can I correctly call a method within the UI thread without producing a memory leak? Or is it possible that there isn't a memory leak?

Edit1
Function called, in the UI thread:

```
    public void actualizeLog() {
        // Called from SendPost thread
        final TextView textLog = findViewById(R.id.textViewLog);
        String serverString;
        serverString = "\t\t" + getServerStatus();
        serverString = getTextLog() + "\t\t" + getCameraStatus() + serverString
                + "\t\t" + getSystemStatus();
        serverString=serverString + "\n" + textLog.getText();
        textLog.setText(serverString);
        setServerStatus("");
        setCameraStatus("NoFoto");
    }
```

And `instance` also in UI:

```
  static MainActivity instance;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      instance = this;
       …..
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what Android Studio Profiler is reporting?

Comment: @RobertGrossman http://megasynergy.com/imagenes/NoGC.bmp before force GC    http://megasynergy.com/imagenes/NoGC.bmp after force GC. Sorry, don't know how to show pictures...

Comment: @RobertGrossman Those screenshots were taken using first approach, after 4 or 5 minutes/starts of thread.

Comment: Is `instance` static?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Yes, it is `static`

Comment: @DanielContarinoThat's your issue. Anything in android that inherits from or uses `Context`, if declared satatic, causes leaks.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Ok. So, what is the alternative for calling `actualizeLog`?

Comment: Can you share the code of the function?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal  OK. I added Edit1 to my question.

Comment: Write your own interface. Make `MainActivity` implement it, and in that implementation, call `actualizeLog`.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Could you please elaborate the idea? How could I call `actualizeLog` from another thread?